# Cannot group list to print properly, also broken get function?

Tags: python, for-loop, parsing, html-table

```
SymbolTime (NY)Message
FAMI08/14/20, 19:59:52Block trade.  At the bid. (NYSEArca)
KTOV08/14/20, 19:59:31Block trade.  At the ask.
```

The information above is what I am parsing.

I am running into two issues. One being I cannot print the entire row of information as a group, it prints individually.

The second; I cannot print the href element. The program will print the first href, then the code breaks. I This is my code;

```
def function_time():
   global url, scan_type, name
   response = session.get(url)
   response = session.get
   soup = bs(response.text, 'html.parser')
   data = soup.findAll()
   page = requests.get(url)
   doc = lh.fromstring(page.content)
    #Parse data that are stored between <tr>..</tr> of HTML
   tr_elements = doc.xpath('//tr')
   tr_elements = doc.xpath('//tr')
    #Create empty list
   col=[]
   i=0
 for t in tr_elements[1]:
    name=t.text_content()
    #link = t.find('a').get('href')
    #print(link) #finds first then breaks 
    print (Fore.GREEN+name)
    col.append((name,[]))
    time.sleep(1)

function_time()
```

Currently prints as

```
FAMI
08/14/2020
Block Trade
```

I want to print it as;
`FAMI 08/14/2020 Block Trade`  , and to fix the href function (currently ends due to no get function error, despite printing the first one.)

I am still learning the ropes and could not figure how to phrase my question while researching. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
 x = []

 for t in tr_elements[1]:
    name=t.text_content()
    #link = t.find('a').get('href')
    #print(link) #finds first then breaks 
    x.append(name)
    col.append((name,[]))
    time.sleep(1)
print(' '.join(x))
```

A quick rundown:

- .join concatenates all the items in a list into a string, joined by whatever you defined in the string before it (in this case, ' ').
- We are appending `name` to a list instead of printing it out right away.

Comment: Thank you! This just helped me join them together. I used "new_name = ', '.join(x)" and now it prints as "NAME, DATE, INFO." It is still printing each element one by one, before printing the joined string. How can I have it just print the full string, instead of each piece on by one, and then the full string?

Comment: Remove `print (Fore.GREEN+name)`

Answer (score 1):

How about using regular expression?

Suppose your data is all in the same structure as your example.

```py
import re

strs = '''
SymbolTime (NY)Message
<a href="/StockInfo/?symbol=FAMI">FAMI</a>08/14/20, 19:59:52Block trade.  At the bid. (NYSEArca)
<a href="/StockInfo/?symbol=KTOV">KTOV</a>08/14/20, 19:59:31Block trade.  At the ask.
'''

patterns = [
    re.compile(r'(?<=>)\w+(?=</a>)'), 
    re.compile(r'\d+/\d+/\d+'), 
    re.compile(r'(?<=:\d\d)[\w\s]+(?=.)')
]
# First pattern: match ticker
# Second pattern: match date
# Third pattern: match trade type

for s in strs.split('\n'):  # Split your document into lines
    if 'href' in s:  # If 'href' in this line, parse this line
        results = []
        for pattern in patterns:
            results.append(pattern.findall(s)[0])  # Find the three elements one by one
        result_str = ' '.join(results)  # Combine them into one string
        print(result_str)
```

Result:

```
'FAMI 08/14/20 Block trade'
'KTOV 08/14/20 Block trade'
```

---

For your first question, you can solve in two ways:

```py
print('FAMI', end=' ')
print('08/14/20', end=' ')
print('Block trade', end=' ')
```

or

```py
s = ' '.join(['FAMI', '08/14/20', 'Block trade')
print(s)
```

Comment: Wow. Incredibly appreciative! I should of used re to begin with lol. It works while running your code. I added it appropriately and it is still printing each individually before the new joined string. Now I cannot seem to find the sweet spot.   
    #Create empty list
   col=[]
    #Store the contents of the website under doc
   for s in col.split('\n'):  # Split your document into lines

It breaks